# What is a citra hop, and how does it differ from other hops?

Tags: hops

I was offered a beer the other day that was reportedly made with citra hops. What are citra hops? Why should I care that my beer is made with them?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Citra is a registered trademark since 2007. Citra Brand hops have fairly high alpha acids and total oil contents with a low percentage of cohumulone content and  imparts interesting citrus and tropical fruit characters to beer.

For more information, you can read the [Wikipedia article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_hop_varieties#Citra_brand_HBC_394_cv) on the Citra brand.